# Escaping Backslash using awk and gsub

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, gsub

In my project there is an existing function i can't modify that has this line:

`gawk -v n=$OCCURENCE "/$OLD/$EXTRA{gsub(\"$OLD\",\"$NEW\")}1" $FILE_TO_AWK`

In my case for $occurence and $extra, it gives:

`gawk -v n=- "/$OLD/{gsub(\"$OLD\",\"$NEW\")}1" $FILE_TO_AWK`

Now here is the part i'm struggling with,
I try to replace this pattern : ReturnCode=\"200\" ($old) by another pattern.
I've been trying so many things but i keep failing because of the backslash and the double quote.

If i have:

```
[12/12/2014 12/34] 123 /url/test.gsp ReturnCode=\"500\" 12234
```

I would like to have this :

```
[12/12/2014 12/34] 123 /url/test.gsp 500 12234
```

I tried things like this :
`gawk -v n=- "/ReturnCode=\\\"500\\\"/{gsub(\"ReturnCode=\\\"500\\\"\",\"500\")}1" fichier.txt`
It didn't work

Using octal code 042 worked for double quote but didn't for backslash... I'm out of ideas so I'd be thankful if you could help me
Thanks !

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but just to remind: double quote `"` and backslash is a special regex characters, so you need to escape them by putting backslash before. So in your case patters would be `\\\"200\"\\`

Comment: So for clarification, are you asking which value to use for $NEW?

Comment: No, the $new is not a problem, this is ReturnCode=\"200\" as $old that is. I know that \ and " are specials caracters and i did try to escape them without success

Comment: To make this more clear, could you provide a sample input and desired output? Also, the way to handle variables here is a bit weird, it might be better to use `-v` to "convert" bash variables into awk variables and not having to worry about escaping: `awk -v old="$OLD" '$0 ~ old'`, etc.

Comment: I can't change hos the awk is done. I'm gonna provide an example of what i want  above

Comment: `OLD='ReturnCode=\\"500\\"' NEW='500'` followed by `awk "/$OLD/{gsub(/$OLD/,"$NEW")}1"` does what you want, or at least so it seems to me...

Comment: FWIW, the reason this cannot work without changing the awk code is that `$OLD` is between `//` in one place and `""` in another, and `"` needs to be escaped in the latter but cannot be in the former. And if you're changing the code anyway, you might as well do it properly with `-v varname="$OLD"` instead of direct substitution of shell variables into awk code (which leaves you vulnerable to code injection).

Answer (score 0):

When things get tricky I like to use single-quotes around my AWK scripts and pass the values in as variables `-v OLD="$OLD" -vNEW="$NEW"` then it's easier to debug by printing things out from within the AWK code.

But I actually think "sed" might be a better tool for this job, with a capturing-expression to preserve the return code:

```
MATCH='url\/test'
OLD='ReturnCode=\\\"\([0-9]*\)\\\"'
NEW='\1'
sed -e "/$MATCH/ { s@$OLD@$NEW@g }" $FILE
```